# Some req.session variables not saving (express-session)

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am setting up an OAuth2 flow that needs to send some extra variables to the callback. When I check req.session in the authorize call, the values for the variables are properly set. The next step is to hit the "callback" route.

```
router.post('/api/personas/authorize', async (req, res) => {
    
    const source = await personaController.getSourceInformation(req.body.source)
    req.session.exchangeURL = source.token_exchange_url;
    req.session.exchangeFields = source.exchange_fields; 
    console.log('REQ', req.session)
    req.session.save()
    const url = constructAuthURL(source)
    res.send(url);

})
```

In the console.log('REQ') call, both the exchangeURL and exchangeFields variables are set properly.

Then, we hit the callback route:

```
router.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
}
```

Those exchange variables are not set. The sessionIDs are the same between the calls and the sid cookie is being sent in both requests. Additionally, in both requests, there are some custom variables that are retained between the calls. It appears that just the variables set at /authorize are not persisted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am happy to provide more info!

EDIT:

Here are the headers from the request that hits 'api/personas/authorize':

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '15',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/personas',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AK01XQwFSwwA_q-D8OxALcx--asG23hsB.%2B8j%2BgLX6Eg%2FHhyh3K5wv%2FqpM6Vmp89xX5Kh8%2FFhLMJg'
}
```

And here are the headers from the request that hits '/callback':

```
  headers: {
    host: 'localhost:3000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
    accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    referer: 'https://{XXXX}.salesforce.com/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3AK01XQwFSwwA_q-D8OxALcx--asG23hsB.%2B8j%2BgLX6Eg%2FHhyh3K5wv%2FqpM6Vmp89xX5Kh8%2FFhLMJg'
  }
```

Comment: How quickly does the /callback route get hit after you do `res.send(url)`?  I ask because your are not waiting for `req.session.save()` to complete so an immediate request from the client may arrive before the sesssion variables have been properly saved (race condition).

Comment: Another possibility is that the client that is making the `/api/personas/authorize` call is not sending cookies so a new session is being created and thus the data is not saved with the original session.  How is this API being called?  Is the `withCredentials` option being used if this is Javascript from a browser?  If you `console.log(req.session.id)` are you always getting the same ID for this client in each request handler?

Comment: The sessionIDs are the same for both calls and the session cookie is sent with both requests. I will put in a timeout for the callback request and see what happens!

Comment: @jfriend00 unfortunately, no luck with the timeout :( appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: I never said anything about a timeout so I'm not sure what you actually tried for that.

Comment: ah sorry, should have provided more context @jfriend00, i used the timeout to try to avoid the race condition

Comment: The proper way to avoid the race condition is to pass a callback to `req.session.save()` and in the callback, check for errors and put the `res.send()` inside that callback.  Timeouts are never the right way to fix race conditions.

Comment: @jfriend00 understood. Used the callback method, but the problem persists unfortunately.

Comment: If a value isn't still in the session on a future request, then there's only two possibilities left.  1. Your session isn't saving properly or 2. The client isn't passing the right cookie to get united with the proper session object.  It pretty much has to be one of those two things.

Comment: One more thing.  Is it the SAME client that issues the `/callback` request as issues the `/api/personas/authorize` request?

Comment: @jfriend00, the request to /callback is coming from a 3rd party API (salesforce in this case), but the session cookie is still available and correct when I print the request. Even when I test with a request directly from the client, the values set in /api/personas/authorize are not available. Will do some further testing

Comment: After further testing, it appears that I am only actually able to set values on req.session the first time I access session object, during the login flow.

Comment: Can you show your session related middleware?  And, what form of session storage are you using?  And, are you 200% sure that the same session cookie is coming back on both requests?

Comment: If the `/callback` request is coming from a different client endpoint than `/api/personas/authorize`, then there's no way it can have the same session cookie and thus the same session!  Cookies are stored in the client.

Comment: Edited to include more information from the headers of each request. As you can see the  cookie is there in both instances. I am using redis to store sessions.

Comment: I'm out of ideas without the ability to debug myself.

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but it is now working after some seemingly inconsequential changes. I am going to keep digging, but frankly, I have no idea. Appreciate the help @jfriend00!

Comment: Unless some stuck and corrupted cookie or something finally got flushed, these things tend to come back later if you don't fully understand their root cause.  I guess I'm glad it's working now, but not sure that means the cause is really gone.  Perhaps some more robust error logging in your session manager and in  .save()` in case there was some sort of error in communicating with redis.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into this as well, and it appears that in some cases, the session data might not save quickly enough.

In my case, I was using [connect-session-knex](https://github.com/gx0r/connect-session-knex).

I had one request that saved some session data, then respond with a redirect. The second request (from the redirect) was not seeing the updated session values.

Per the [express-session `session.save()`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionsavecallback) docs:

> There are some cases where it is useful to call this method, for example, redirects, long-lived requests or in WebSockets.

Thing is, I wanted to call it and ensure the `save()` finished before `res.send` sent back the redirect.

I found that someone had added a PR to `express-session` with a promise-based `save()` call, presumably for this purpose, but the PR has been left without being merged. So I came up with this workaround (also posted [there](https://github.com/expressjs/session/pull/701#issuecomment-1553852225)):

```
import { promisify } from 'util';

...

// Create a "saveAsync" method--a promise-based version of save(),
// and make it available to other routes.
//
// (This could also be done via app.use())
router.use((req, _res, next) => {
  req.session.saveAsync = promisify(req.session.save.bind(req.session));
  next();
});

...

router.post('/xyz', async (req, res, next)  => {
  // do stuff that changes the session

  ...

  // save session, blocking response until this is done 
  await req.session.saveAsync();
   
  res.send(...);
});
```

(FYI: the above example is a bit simplified. I actually use [express-async-handler](https://github.com/Abazhenov/express-async-handler) in my routes.)